# WCF in Mono 2.10.9 performance issues

Tags: c#, linux, wcf, performance, mono

I have a simple WCF host and client which run fine in Windows but suffer extremely bad performance on Mono 2.10.8/9.

The WCF host is running in a self-hosted console app.
WCF client is also a simple console app.
They're using netTcpBinding without any security.

Here's the host app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior" name="EmployeeServiceLib.EmployeeService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8888/EmployeeService/tcp"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ultra" name="EmployeeService"
          contract="EmployeeServiceLib.IEmployeeService" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="ultra" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Streamed">
          <reliableSession enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

client app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="EmployeeService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
                    transferMode="Streamed" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="65536" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8888/EmployeeService/tcp"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EmployeeService"
                contract="EmployeeService.IEmployeeService" name="EmployeeService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

WCF Service class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
    AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
    private readonly List<Employee> m_Employees = new List<Employee>();

    #region IEmployeeService Members

    public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        m_Employees.Add(employee);
    }

    // ... snipped ...
}
```

What the client does is calling an OperationContract 100 times and benchmark the calls.

```
var employee = new Employee { ... };
var client = new EmployeeServiceClient("EmployeeService", "net.tcp://localhost:8888/EmployeeService/tcp");
client.Open();
Console.Write("Adding 100 employees...");
var startTime = Environment.TickCount;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    client.AddEmployee(employee);
}
var timeTaken = Environment.TickCount - startTime;
Console.WriteLine(" Done.");
```

Benchmark result:

.NET 4.0 = 62 ms

Mono 2.11.1 = 1672 ms

Mono 2.10.9 in Debian 6 running in VM = 9632 ms (CPU usage hovering around 1%)

What can I do to speed up the performance of WCF on Mono esp in Debian?

Comment: How did you install mono on Debian 6? I thought it wasn't officially supported yet!

Comment: Mono on Debian 6 is definitely supported. For later versions of Mono (such as 2.10.9) though, you'll need to compile from source.